SwiftUI PhotosPicker select video file size larger than original file
I am using PhotosPicker to select one video in iPhone album. The original video size is 5.3MB, as here:

After I run code select this video and check the size it's 8.9MB.
here is the code:
import AVKit
import PhotosUI
import SwiftUI

struct Movie: Transferable {
    let url: URL

    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        FileRepresentation(contentType: .movie) { movie in
            SentTransferredFile(movie.url)
        } importing: { received in
            
            print("Importing \(received)")
            print("receive \(received.file.fileSize)")
            
            let copy = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "abc.mp4")

            return Self.init(url: copy)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
   
    @State private var selectedItem: PhotosPickerItem?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PhotosPicker("Select movie", selection: $selectedItem, matching: .videos)

        }
        .onChange(of: selectedItem) { _ in
            Task {
                do {
                    if let movie = try await selectedItem?.loadTransferable(type: Movie.self) {
                        print("movie \(movie)")
                    }
                } catch {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

URLExtension
extension URL {
var fileSize: String {
    do {
        let resources = try resourceValues(forKeys:[.fileSizeKey])
        return ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(resources.fileSize ?? 0), countStyle: .file)
    } catch {
        return ""
    }
}

After run this code the print is:
receive 8.9 MB

Are there any issues of the code? thanks.
EDIT
Tried UIImagePickerController the result is 5.3MB, same as original.
